# Event unsubscribe / resubscribe on property change

Tags: c#, events

I often write code like that:

```
MyObject property;
MyObject Property
{
    get { return property; }
    set {
            if (property != null)
                property.Changed -= property_Changed; // unsubscribe from the old value
            property = value;
            property.Changed += property_Changed; // subscribe to the new value
        }
}
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to make the unsubscribing automatic.
Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean to check the whole setter for null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using Extensions Methods might be what you are looking for.

You could try something like this.

```
private MyProperty property;
public MyProperty Property
{
    get { return property; }
    set { property.SubPubValue(value, property_Changed); }
}

private static void property_Changed(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SubPubValue<T>(this T value, T setValue, PropertyChangedEventHandler property_Changed) where T : MyProperty
    {
        if (setValue != null)
            value.PropertyChanged -= property_Changed;
        value = setValue;
        if (setValue != null)
            value.PropertyChanged += property_Changed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's about as elegant as you can get with the idea you're trying to implement. Of course, you have a logic bug in that `value` could be null when passed in, and thus `property.Changed += property_Changed` would explode.

Basically, if you assign a new object, you want to unsubscribe from the old element's event and attach to the new elements event.

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this, if you really need to unsubscribe/subscribe on every property change:

```
MyObject Property
{
    get { return property; }
    set {
            //unsubscribe always, if it's not null 
            if(property !=null)
               property.Changed -= property_Changed;

            //assign value 
            property = value;

            //subscribe again, if it's not null
            if (property != null)                            
                property.Changed += property_Changed; 

        }
}
```